# PostMessage WM_CLOSE returns 1

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I have the following function:

```
Public Function CloseWindow(ByVal uHandle As Int32) As Boolean

    Dim iRet As Integer = PostMessage(uHandle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)

    Return CBool(iRet = 0)

End Function
```

The function in run-time is like this:

```
    Dim iRet As Integer = PostMessage(uHandle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)

    If (iRet <> 0) Then
        Dim iLastErr As Integer = Err.LastDllError()
        'This always returns 0, so I don't know what to make up of it
        Stop
    End If
```

In some cases, iRet returns 1.

Can anbody tell me what that might mean?

Comment: The return type of PostMessage() is Boolean, not Integer.  1 is just another way to write True.  Great, it did not fail, stop looking for a nonexisting problem.

Comment: What's wrong with the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx)? *"If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero."* It's unclear, why you hope that it returns anything but 1.

Comment: Are you expecting `PostMessage()` to return the result returned by the window procedure, like `SendMessage()` does? It cannot. `PostMessage()` simply says "put this message in the queue so it can run later; I have other things to do right now". There's no telling when that message will be handled; all you can be certain of is that `GetMessage()` will at some point in the future get that message out. You might have already existed by the time the message is handled, so there's no place for the message to return anything to. As a result, `PostMessage()` only returns a success/failure state.

Comment: Again, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) tells you to call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) on failure only (you are calling it on success). Are you going to ask a real question, too, once we are done handling your successful API calls?

Comment: @IInspectable I have updated my question accordingly. GetLastError returns 0.

Comment: Yes, and I responded to that. Don't call `GetLastError` on success.

Comment: Why won't you read the documentation?

Comment: The thing is that the function doesn't close the window. Else I wouldn't have bothered asking the question.

Comment: Again, did you read the documentation?

Comment: Posting `WM_CLOSE` to a window is a request. That request can be denied. The return value of `PostMessage` will not indicate whether the window was closed/destroyed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WM_CLOSE` is a **sent** message, not a **posted** message.  A *posted* message cannot return a value to the poster.

The return value of `PostMessage()` is a `BOOL` that simply indicates whether the message was successfully added to the window's message queue, NOT whether the message was actually processed.

If you need to handle the `LRESULT` value that `WM_CLOSE` returns to indicate whether the close was accepted or rejected, you need to use `SendMessage()` (or related function) instead of `PostMessage()`.

If the window is owned by the thread that is sending `WM_CLOSE`, you can use `DestroyWindow()` to actually close it (unless its window procedure passes the `WM_CLOSE` message to `DefWindowProc()`, in which case it will call `DestroyWindow()` for you).  But if the window is owned by another thread, all you can do is send `WM_CLOSE` to ask it to close itself.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that you cannot `DestroyWindow()` to a foreign window. If the window is foreign, `WM_CLOSE` is all you have.